# Convert dates from csv file to sentence format

Tags: csv, python-3.x

I am trying to convert the dates from a csv file to sentence format.  For example: “8/27/2012” to August 27, 2012 and  “1/4/2013” to January 4, 2013.  This is the code I have:

```
def getStockData(company):
    baseurl = 'http://quote.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=GOOG&f=sl1d1t1c1ohgvj1pp2owern&e=.csv'
    web_page = urllib.request.urlopen(baseurl)
    lines = web_page.read().decode()
    web_page.close()
    read = csv.reader([lines])
    row = next(read)
    print('The last trade for', row[0], 'is $'+row[1], ', change rate is '+row[11], 'on '+row[2],'. The open was '+row[5],'and the previous close was '+row[10],'.')
```

Row[2] indicates the date.  Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: see https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime

Comment: ok, i decided to use row[2].strftime('%B %d %Y') in my print statement but then it gives me "TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly", what is the list that I need to convert to a str?

Comment: @holaprofesor: `row[2]` is a `str` (no idea why you see `list`), and `strftime` is not a method of `str`. You need `datetime.date.strptime` to parse the `str`, then `datetime.data.strftime` to format it in the new form. I have no idea what you did to get that error, because the code you give makes no sense for that error.

Comment: so I need to parse the str using strptime in a line before I use strftime in the print statement? @ShadowRanger

Comment: @holaprofesor yes you do

Comment: thank you both, fixed it

Answer (score 0):

To change the format of a `date`/`datetime` from one text format to another, the easiest way is to:

- convert to an actual `date`/`datetime` using the `.strptime()` method
- convert back to text using the `.strftime()` method

For example:

```
from datetime import datetime
close_date = datetime.strptime('%m/%d/%Y')
close_date_text = close_date.strftime('%B %d, %Y')
```